# What is the difference between linear transformation and linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations

What is the difference between *linear transformation* and *linear operator*?

In our linear algebra class, we learned that, if
$$\textbf{T}:\textbf{V}\rightarrow\textbf{W}\quad\vec{v},\vec{u}\in\textbf{V}$$
$$\textbf{T}(\vec{v}+\vec{u})=\textbf{T}\vec{v}+\textbf{T}\vec{u}$$
$$\textbf{T}(c\vec{v})=c\textbf{T}(\vec{v})\quad\textbf{c}\in\mathbb{R}$$

then $\textbf{T}$ is linear transformation from $\textbf{V}$ to $\textbf{W}$.

Comment: To me, they are synonymous. But I do use both terms, depending on the context.

Comment: Yes, I believe also that they are the same.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, they mean one and the same thing, though I've found that the word "operator" predominates in the infinite-dimensional context of functional analysis.

Comment: They are the same thing. Some authors limit their uses of the term "operator" for those linear transformation whose domain coincides with co-domain. This is especially true when the elements of the underlying vector spaces are functions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For many people, the two terms are identical. However, my personal preference (and one which some other people also adopt) is that a linear operator on $X$ is a linear transformation $X \rightarrow X$. This is why it is common to hear phrases like "Let $T$ be a linear operator on a separable Hilbert space" without specifying the codomain.

Comment: This is the differentiation they adopted on wikipedia, come here because when reading the topic on wikipedia, I'm surprised there actually is a difference!

Answer (score 5):

They are in a way synonymous, but I learned it this way.

Consider a rotation in $R^2$ of some vector. This is a linear transformation. The operator defining this transformation is an angle rotation.

Consider a dilation of a vector by some factor. That is also a linear transformation. The operator this particular transformation is a scalar multiplication.

The *operator* is sometimes referred to as what the linear transformation exactly entails. Other than that, it makes no difference really.

Comment: In other words, you are saying that _transformation_ refers to a class of functions, whereas _operator_ refers to specific instances. 
I suppose, such distinction can be useful when talking about groups and actions.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add a little something even though for most people the distinction will never arise.

Sometimes mathematicians define things like a polynomial $P(D)$ in an operator $D$. In most cases the operator $D$ will be a linear operator; which remains consistent with the fact that a linear operator $ T: V \to V$ has a *square* matrix representation. We know a polynomial in a square matrix is a valid thing and so nothing breaks.

On the other hand, an arbitrary transformation $L : V \to W$ may not have a square representation (say dimensions of $V,W$ are different); so if we just blindly say they are the same thing, one misses this subtlety. So if someone asked me, I would say there is distinction between a linear operator (the domain and co-domain match) a linear transformation (the domain and co-domain need not match) in that every linear operator is a linear transformation, whereas not every linear transformation is a linear operator.